# MySQL Batch Inserts Inserting Very Slowly

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, performance

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("LoadData.txt"))){
        final Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://ipAddress:port/database?user=username&password=password&useServerPrepStmts=false&rewriteBatchedStatements=true");
        String sCurrentLine;
        final PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("insert ignore into emails (email) value (?)");
        int count = 0;
        final int batchSize = 1000;
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            ps.setString(1, sCurrentLine);
            ps.addBatch();
            if(++count % batchSize == 0) {
                ps.executeBatch();
            }
        }
        ps.executeBatch();
        ps.close();
        connection.close();
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Even with the above code, batch inserting is extremely slow, taking a couple of minutes per each 1000 rows. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%'.  There are several things to check (engine, cache, datatype, indexes, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting an answer in case this messes with someone else in the future:

My SQL query had the keyword "**value**". The keyword must be "**values**" for the batch inserts to work.

Comment: No, `VALUE` and `VALUES` are (mostly) synonyms.  I just tested it, and had no trouble inserting multiple rows with `VALUE`.